# Codeigniter & $_GET variables w/Sagepay

Tags: php, codeigniter, input, get, opayo

I am integrating Sagepay into my Codeigniter v2.1 application - for some reason I am have issues get the crypt data that is returned from Sagepay within the $_GET querystring.

Whenever I try the variable from the $_GET it returns as FALSE, similarly the $_GET array itself returns a empty array.

The URL is as follows:

```
http://mydomain.com/packages/payment_status/success/?crypt=IgAdEBkXOhwsHRAATkVESF5RQkNDSEJEW1BWSVpDWVNDQUFXXVJXVCI1ICAOLApZFEJMIUVMRiMvSVoxMFxeMTMjW0kuQDAkXjBGIVoiK0FAUzcwQRhINxsTABAASTkuSDcbEwAQADATEQ8NA09EVUNEVl9OMAcXVCQGAB4KHA0cEwAMHBpWEg8XTyEBBhARBRYIEQNcUjELNQMRBioAT0VVQE1OUFpCLiQnJiVGSzYrJzogPTEqVDUqKiFPPzUxMDxWKiAoNlQ1ARcGExYdNgoBAQkHSTgqOikuJjctNjBQNQEXGzEbARYmExYbCBtPOionOTcxLSwqNlImJUYkAB0RAwZJKDIgNS0rIEk1HQMHNR8BU1RJQTA2FhcDFws3GxMAEABJOCo6Jyc3Ny42MFAmDxYLJg0VFkkgLD0lST4VFgdAMgwJDRsBSVVDREBDLwkABxoRTkZDVUBUXw==

    $crypt = $this->input->get('crypt');
    var_dump($crypt); // returns FALSE
```

I've turned on the following config settings:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING";
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?'; // to allow the '?' character in the url
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't use the query string method, but can you show a sample of the url that's being used to call this code?

Comment: i've added the URL being returned

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked a few times before. Look on the related links on the right.

Comment: ok, now i can see it's a mix of friendly url and get.  You are missing one config option, then you need to do some work to either put the var in $_GET or use REQUEST.  See answer.

Comment: Can you try and set `uri_protocol` to AUTO instead? I am using a similar payment provider that insists on using GET instead of POST when doing callbacks. My CI implementation allows both and can read the values perfectly fine when using AUTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this method in the end..
MY_Controller.php

```
function current_url() {
$CI =& get_instance();

$url = $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
return $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? $url.'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : $url;
```

}

// in my controller
        $parts = parse_url(current_url());

```
    if (isset($parts['query']) && is_array($parts))
    {
        parse_str($parts['query'], $querystring);
        krumo($querystring);
    }
```

This seems to be fine for now :) thanks - have changed the uri setting to PATH_INFO and made some tweaks to the htaccess file too.

Answer (score 0):

When you activate query strings, you should use this syntax

```
index.php?c=controller&m=method
```

For further information, read this :

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter doesn't use the $_GET or $_POST variables.

`$this->input->get()` and `$this->input->post()`

are how you access them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
$var = $this->input->xss_clean($_REQUEST['var']);
```